# Regex for last value in quoted CSV of pipe-separated rows of values

Tags: regex, string, csv

I am trying to use regex to select the last section of data appearing before the pipes of each row.  Here is my sample data:

```
"|35 CHESTNUT PARK RD |CITY OF TORONTO|5300000|2014\/11|43.679108|-79.386780|190410123000100|3977000|PLAN 233E LOT 3|",
"|39 CHESTNUT PARK RD |CITY OF TORONTO|2000000|2004\/04|43.679179|-79.386542|190410123000200|4106000|PLAN 233E LOT 4|",
"|43 CHESTNUT PARK RD |CITY OF TORONTO|1847625|1997\/11|43.679223|-79.386343|190410123000300|4279000|PLAN 233E LOT 5|"
```

The data consists of three pipe-separated rows, but within each row there are a number of data sections separated by pipes.

The data I want is the value of each row, ie from the above input:

```
PLAN 233E LOT 3
PLAN 233E LOT 4
PLAN 233E LOT 5
```

I haven't been able to figure out the correct regex statement to select this data.

Comment: Any attempts? Which lang you're running?

Comment: I am running python regex.  I haven't tried anything noteworthy yet.  Still playing with it.

Comment: `str.split('|')[-2]`

Comment: is this data present in single string or these are different string? If its single string you can use **[this](https://regex101.com/r/bU0dC8/1)**

Comment: @rock321987 Post it as an answer.

Comment: @CinCout Its still not clear whether it is a single string or a list of string..anyway I will post it assuming its a single string

Comment: The rows were separated by commas. The question is now edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches your target:

```
[^|]+(?=\|")
```

In English, this means "one or more non-pipe chars that are immediately followed by a pipe then end of line".

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/NU5toUVu8V).

Comment: you are changing the meaning of whole question that was asked

Comment: @rock in what way have I changed it at all?

Comment: you have removed comma from string given by user

Comment: @rock what comma? There is no comma

Comment: You are assuming it to be a list containing three strings..OP has not yet clarified whether its a list of string or single string

Comment: seems like someone edited before you about comma and replaced it with pipe

Comment: @rock My regex will work for any number of lines and any number of pipe-delimited values per line. If lines have literally been catenated with commas, it's a trivial change to make it work. I'll watch this space...

Comment: To clarify, my data is a list of comma-separated strings.  Someone has edited my question and removed the strings for some reason.

Comment: @DanielAttard then you must roll it back! Wonder how blindly people approve edits!

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct.. I don't have any doubt about that.. its the edit that I was talking

Comment: @dan are the quotes literally around each row too?

Comment: @Bohemian, yes, the quotes are around each row too, and comma-separated.  Here is how the JSON data looks http://pastebin.com/SrqqAJAM

Comment: @dan I have modified the question and my answer to what I believe you want.